# Make my php wait the end of my python script

Tags: php, python, shell, execution

I'm trying to execute a Python script from a Php one.
After trying a lot of things found on the internet, I'm still struggling with this problem : My php does not wait my python script to finish.

Indeed, It blocks when I have to import a loud class (called NeuralNetwork) in my python code.

I'd like to find a way to make my php wait the end of my python script execution.

Thank you !
(PS: sorry in advance if my english is bad)

Imports in my python file (NeuralNetworkFinal.py):

```
    from ControlerRn import Controler_rn
    from controler import controler
    import sys
    from NeuralNetwork import NeuralNetwork
```

The way I run it in my php file (formulaire.php) :

```
<?php
    $variableNR = 'py C:\Users\cefyo\Desktop\2018-l3al1v2\branches\NeuralNetworkFinal.py ';

    $command = escapeshellcmd($variableNR);
    $outputNR = shell_exec($command);
    echo $outputNR;

?>
```

I already tried to use :

```
< /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

and

```
   set_time_limit(0);
```

in my Php script but nothing happens.

When I print something between each import, theyare displayed in my $output until the line

```
 from NeuralNetwork import NeuralNetwork
```

Comment: how do you execute your php script?

Comment: by clicking a button sir

Comment: Did the duplicate question help?

Comment: Not really, we dont have the same issue. I'm still working it and I'll share if find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, this answer might look a bit tricky but...

```
<?php
$variableNR = 'py C:\Users\cefyo\Desktop\2018-l3al1v2\branches\NeuralNetworkFinal.py ';

$command = escapeshellcmd($variableNR);
$outputNR = shell_exec($command);
while(outputNR == null){ // idk if the default value is null check that please
    //do nothing
}
// echo should happen only after 'while' condition changed 
echo $outputNR;
?>
```

Comment: It doesn't work but that was well thought, thank you for your answer Marco !